# AjaxToolkit ModalPopupExtender: How do I set focus to a control in the popup Panel?

Tags: asp.net, focus, modalpopupextender

When the user pushes the Button, I'd like to display a modal dialog box to capture a couple of values from text boxes and submit these values to the server.

When the modal box is shown, I'd like the cursor to be placed in the txtFirst textbox.

How do I do this? I've had trouble with registerscript commands before, so if one is needed, I hope the syntax, if you provide it, is correct.

Thanks

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MyModalSimple.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyModalSimple" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function onOk() {            
            form1.submit();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <cc1:modalpopupextender id="Button1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" targetcontrolid="Button1"
            popupcontrolid="pnlModal" okcontrolid="btnOK" cancelcontrolid="btnCancel"   DropShadow="true"  OnOkScript="onOk();">

        </cc1:modalpopupextender>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlModal" runat="server" Style="display: None1" 
            BackColor="#CCCCCC">
            <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" Text="First"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLast" runat="server" Text="Last"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, how could I change the above code so that the modal dialog was displayed as a result of a *selection* of a dropdownlist item? If I set the targetcontrolid="DropDownList1", the dialog box is display when it drops rather than when  a selection is made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example can be found [here](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/ModalPopup_Postback.aspx). In essence you are using javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post my 2nd part question separately

Answer (score 1):

I know this was already answered, but here's an easier code:

C#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "FocusScript", "setTimeout(function(){$get('" + btnOk.ClientID + "').focus();}, 100);", true);
```

VB:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "FocusScript", "setTimeout(function(){$get('" + btnOk.ClientID + "').focus();}, 100);", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Style="display: None1"` from control panel